# Is there any API for Booking Flights?

Tags: ios

I am working in an application which has the requirement of booking flights from the app.
Is there any such API for the same? I need some information if there is any available.

Answer (score 1):

You can check

Wego http://www.wego.com/api/flights/docs

or

http://www.programmableweb.com/category/travel/api

http://www.cleartrip.com/api/docs/air-api/

http://www.wego.com/api/flights/docs

http://www.programmableweb.com/news/5-travel-apis-comparison-to-booking/2007/10/29

http://www.programmableweb.com/news/134-travel-apis-kayak-yahoo-travel-and-hotelscombined/2012/02/28

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Skyscanner has an API which I believe returns prices: http://api.skyscanner.net/api/ajax/documentation.html and they have a pretty good coverage of all major airlines (because they are a forwarder and not a reseller).

https://www.tripit.com/developer

https://github.com/Perennials/travelsdk-ios

http://uk.flightaware.com/commercial/flightxml/